# PHP cant download image with readfile

Tags: php, jpeg

This is my code:

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

test.jpg is a file on my system. I can open it and nothing is wrong with it. The download gets started but when i try to open the downloaded image, it says that it cant be opened. Im testing it on Chrome. Does someone have a solution? Thanks a lot.

Edit: the downloaded .jpg is only 23kb where as the file i want is 135kb.

Comment: Where did you dumpped file contents to output stream?

Comment: Do a `file_exists()` check before output.

Comment: You can open the downloaded file on a text editor. What is the content? A PHP error message?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch i get the content of the image like this: TUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ         
ÿÄ µ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set header

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
ob_clean();
exit;
```

Comment: @NoéPerracini Glad that it worked. Here is the explanation for the answer, content type was incorrect for jpeg images and everytime you download files from the header ob_clean() will clear the previous buffer there by reduce the chances of getting garbage file.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing readfile with echo `file_get_contents($file)`

Comment: I still get the same result